Rotation of axes in 3d
I was following a research article in which I came across the rotation of axes (uvw) two times with its formula mentioned. I am not a mathematician, but what could I find online were the transformation matrices in 3d. We could multiply two matrices to get the final rotation. But what was mentioned in the article was different. They just calculate two components using some formula and then the third component is calculated by their cross product (which makes sense as it would be perpendicular to the plane formed by the two). Firstly, the rotation is about u axis with angle beta, then second rotation is about v axis with angle alpha.
Figure showing rotation of axes from uvw to u1v1w1
I could not understand the formula mentioned for u1 and v1. The formulae that they wrote are as follows:
$u_1= 0u + \cos(\beta) v + \sin(\beta) w$
$v_1 = \sqrt{(\tan(\alpha)^2 + \tan(\beta)^2 + 1} \cdot (\tan(\alpha) u + \tan(\beta) v + w)$
$w_1 = u_1 \times v_1$
If anyone could explain me I would be very greatful.
Thank you for your response in advance.
Regards

Insert this block of text in your post to make the formulae more legible (press on edit and copy from "begin" to "end" line):
\begin{align*}
u_1 &= 0u + \cos(\beta)v + \sin(\beta) w\
v_1 &= \sqrt{(\tan(\alpha)^2 + tan(beta)^2 + 1} \cdot (\tan(\alpha) u + \tan(\beta) v + w)\
w_1 &= u \times v
\end{align*}
Note the change in the formula for $w$. I'm assuming that the original $u_1 \times v_1$ was a typo.

Welcome to MSE. I've edited your post to make it easier to read, without changing your intentions. I recommend you take a tour with MSE's tour guide to learn how to use MathJax.

I haven't worked out the $v_1$ definition, but it sounds like you are trying to interpret $u_1, v_1, w_1$ as coordinates when they are the (rotated) basis vectors.

"But what was mentioned in the article was different" - No. It has been written out differently, but the underlying calculation is the same. Your three equations express $u_1, v_1, w_1$ as linear combinations of $u, v, w$. (With the $w_1$ equation, you have to substitute in the expressions for $u_1, v_1$ and expand to see it as a linear combination of $u,v,w$. You will also need to use the fact that $w = u \times v, v = w \times u, u = v \times w$.). Matrices are just short-hand ways of writing out linear combinations.

Thank you @RDK for the edits. I will surely look into the details.
Yes the new axes (u1, v1, w1) are formed by rotating the previous axes (u,v,w) as mentioned in the original post and the figure.

@PaulSinclair, Yes the underlying calculation must be the same and we should get the same values. What I get when I apply the rotation matrices is:
$u_1= \cos(\alpha) u + \sin(\alpha) \sin(\beta) v - \sin(\alpha) \cos(\beta) w$
$v_1= 0u + \cos(\beta) v + \sin(\beta) w$
